# Smart contracts and the inherent lack of security in trusting compiled byte code

Tags: contract-development, contract-design, security, evm, trust

Smart contracts on the blockchain are compiled. Is there any system in place to verify all the public dapp contracts do what they propose to be doing?

i.e. this could be done by compiling open-source contracts and verifying contract hash signatures, or in the case of closed-source but public d-apps, potentially decompiling compiled byte code and verifying code paths/function calls, although this is much murkier territory.

See for example https://etherscan.io/address/0xf97e0a5b616dffc913e72455fde9ea8bbe946a2b#code which is the CryptoKitties "gene combination" algorithm. Whilst the rest of CryptoKitties is open-source, this particular code module is closed-source. It has however been reverse engineered - here's a blog post about it, https://medium.com/@sean.soria/cryptokitties-mixgenes-function-69207883fc80. Whilst this is a small code function, there appears to be the possibility that a dapp could launch, proposing and appearing at first glance to be open-source, but in fact containing a hidden time-bomb, e.g. to transfer the balance of Ether to a bad actor's account on a hardcoded future date.

Do we need some framework or service was set up by which all published smart contract code can be validated to some degree?

Comment: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/4623/how-are-end-users-meant-to-build-trust-towards-smart-contracts-and-their-origin?rq=1 is almost a dup

Answer (score 5):

> this could be done by compiling open-source contracts and verifying contract hash signatures

That's pretty much what Etherscan already does. Are you aware of Etherscan's capabilities here? Are you proposing something more than what Etherscan already does?

For smart contracts that don't have published source code, simply don't trust them. (Or trust them if you're capable of auditing the bytecode directly, which I would claim vanishingly few people can do.)

Comment: Right, just found https://etherscan.io/verifyContract. This is part-way there. But take the example of CryptoKitties - countless thousands clearly *do* trust unpublished contract code (in fact are not even aware what "byte code" and "compilation" mean). This is a problem huh..

Comment: I guess I'm proposing something to highlight whenever there is non-verifiable code on the blockchain!

Comment: If someone is trusting a contract without reading the source code, it doesn't really matter whether that code is available or not. (The availability of the code doesn't make the contract any more trustworthy.) Etherscan is the _de facto_ standard for where you find source code that goes with a contract, so I think we already have the tool we need here. The rest is just about user education, and that's going to be a huge uphill battle. :-)

Comment: Etherscan doesn't help when the source is not available. Would it be possible launch an ICO with a hidden timebomb and have users buy in before a security professional audits the code?

I'm thinking a service could exist that proactively monitors the blockchain for non-verifiable source (or non-matching hashes) - it could use Etherscan - but Etherscan does not proactively raise awareness with alerts..

Comment: If someone wants to look at the code, they can look, and if it's not there, then they know it wasn't published (on Etherscan). What would a "proactive" version look like? Telling people about the lack of source code _before_ they looked for it?

Comment: Yes exactly - because obviously most users don't know anything verifying source code. Think about the security alert in browser's address bars if a site's certificate is suspect. See my above comment; "Would it be possible launch an ICO with a hidden timebomb and have users buy in before a security professional audits the code?"

Comment: If a user isn't looking at the source code, it makes no difference whether it's been published or not. If they _are_ looking at the source code, then they don't need anything "proactive." (They'll see that the source code is missing as soon as they try to read it.) So I'm not sure what group of people is helped by something that shows up anywhere other than where the source code is supposed to be.

Answer (score 2):

> [T]his could be done by compiling open-source contracts and
>   verifying contract hash signatures, or in the case of closed-source
>   but public d-apps, potentially decompiling compiled byte code and
>   verifying code paths/function calls, although this is much murkier
>   territory.

If you use the compiler `solc` which compiles solidity code, you can compile the source code that the publisher of the contract claims represent a contract on the blockchain. You have to use the compiler with the flag `--bin-runtime` to get the code which will be placed on the blockchain if you compile and publish the source code in question. Take a look at this answer: [solc bin vs. bin-runtime](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/13086/solc-bin-vs-bin-runtime/13087#13087)

You can then compare the binary code that `solc` returns with the code returned by the call in geth `eth.getCode(contractaddress)` (this call returns the binary which is stored on the address `contractaddress`. This is the EVM code of the contract placed on the blockchain). The binary code of these two operations should match.

Like you state, you can also get familiar with the virtual machine code that Ethereum contracts compile to which is called EVM. If you do that, you will be able to read the content of the contracts directly from the blockchain. The [Yellow Paper](http://gavwood.com/paper.pdf) is a good resource if you want to learn EVM.